# How to configure the output of Tshark/Wireshark .psml file

Tags: xml, wifi, wireshark, tshark, network-analysis

I am creating a simple packet analyzer in Python in which analyzes Tshark `.xml` output files.

Tshark (command line equivalent of Wireshark) has a feature which allows to output all the packets to the .psml file (Packet Summary Markup Language). In Wireshark I can configure the contents of the exported .psml file by adding/removing tabs in the GUI. However, I can't find any option to do this by using a command line in Tshark.

Sample output from Wireshark:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<psml version="0" creator="wireshark/2.0.0">
<structure>
<section>No.</section>
<section>Time</section>
<section>Source</section>
<section>Destination</section>
<section>Protocol</section>
<section>Length</section>
<section>Info</section>
<section>dBm</section>
</structure>

<packet>
<section>1</section>
<section>0.000000</section>
<section>xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx</section>
<section>Broadcast</section>
<section>802.11</section>
<section>223</section>
<section>Beacon frame, SN=1524, FN=0, Flags=........C, BI=100, SSID=xxx</section>
<section>4294967260 dBm</section>
</packet>
```

In Tshark I am getting the output without the section dBm (IEEE 802.11 RSSI). How to configure Tshark to get this data in `.psml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PSML shows the columns that would show up in the summary pane in Wireshark or the output of TShark without `-V`, so you need to request the RSSI column.

Presumably by "adding/removing tabs" you mean "adding/removing columns".

Try running TShark with the command-line option

```
-o gui.column.format:'"No.", "%m", "Time", "%t", "Source", "%s", "Destination", "%d", "Protocol", "%p", "Length", "%L", "Info", "%i", "dBm", "%e"'
```

which specifies which columns to display - or to put in PSML output.

(Unfortunately, there's a bug in Wireshark 2.x where the dBm value is written in PSML as if it were *unsigned*, so, for example, -33 dBm shows up as 4294967263. I've checked in a fix, so it should be fixed when Wireshark 2.0.2 comes out. Wireshark 1.x doesn't have that bug.)